# MailChimp Support: the final "welcome" email with the link to unsubscribe

Tags: php, mysql, mailchimp

I'd like to know, if it is possible to send users to a page of my website, when they click on the link in the so-called  final “welcome” email to let them unsubscribe from my list: I'm asking that, as I already created an unsubscribe_success_page.php, and that's ok, but if a user clicks on that link created from Mailchimp, a new page opens where the user is asked to confirm his email address.
If the one proposed in the page is confirmed, the user gets unsubscribed.

The problem is on that link which shows an anonymous page and not one that I could prepare.
I add only that I use the Mailchimp API with the official PHP wrapper, and via Webhhooks I get all the data, that I save in my MySQl database.

Thanks.
Bye.

Answer (score 0):

MailChimp requires that you use their unsubscribe link in the email campaigns that are sent through their service, so you won't be able to control where the user is sent to immediately after they click the unsubscribe link in your emails.

However, they do have the option for you to set up an unsubscribe success redirect. This means that AFTER they go through the MailChimp unsub process, you can have the user redirected to your own custom unsubscribe page.

This article describes how to set that up:
http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-i-remove-the-unsubscribe-reason-survey/

Comment: Thanks Pietro, as I thought it's impossible to send the users who want to unsubscribe to a personalized page, after they click the link in the "final" welcome email.

Comment: As regards the unsubscribe success redirect I already created that, that's what I meant by my unsubscribe_success_page.php. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: I found also this http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/advanced-customization-of-mailchimps-sign-up-forms but it's only for paid accounts.